# Server responds "bus error" to every command

Tags: linux, centos, hardware, ssd, bus

I have a linux machine dedicated to MySQL server with a pretty high load. Today I woke up and was terrified to see that database server is down. I could connect to it via SSH, but it was responding with `bus error` to each and every command:

```
[root@r1304 home]# ls
Bus error
[root@r1304 home]# tail /var/log/messages
Bus error
[root@r1304 home]# reboot
Bus error
[root@r1304 home]# free -m
Bus error
[root@r1304 home]# chkdisk
Bus error
```

I went to Data Center and did a hard reset, which seemed to help, but after a half an hour situation reapeated and now I can't even connet via SSH anymore.

Any ideas what this could be? how to diagnose such a problem and what are possible fixes?

Server has 32 GB RAM, 2xSSD drives with software RAID

**UPDATE**
According to Zabbix, when MySQL died, number of processes stated to increase drammaticaly, until I did a hard reset. What could those be?

[image: screenshot]
Number of processes

Comment: Those are processes piling up waiting for I/O. Something is happening at the storage layer.

Comment: What was the issue?

Comment: @ewwhite, well, the hard drive completely died. Hello, kingston SSD. I'm bying a new one and restoring from a backup.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your storage system seems to have failed. You can't read from disk at this point.

Can you see the messages in the kernel ring buffer? Look at the output of `dmesg` if the command even works at this point.

Do you have any backups or replication enabled?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, I have cold backups and replication on another server. Does this mean I have replace the hard drives? Unfortunatly, nothing works for me at this point.

Comment: If you have data elsewhere, I would reboot and try to examine the logs in `/var/log/messages` as soon at the system comes up. Look for indicators of filesystem or hardware failure.